# UI-Select case Insensitive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

Is there any way to ignore case between ng-model and select item ?

This issue i have is log.username was a input box instead a dropdown so old username have all different case.

> Example:
>
> log.username = "doej";
>
> lookupOptions.users = [{username:"DoeJ", fullName:"Joe Doe"},
>   {username:"SmithM", fullName:"MarySmith"}]
>
> On load select is empty instead of having "DoeJ"

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Stored By</label>
        <ui-select ng-model="log.username" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Site">{{$select.selected.username}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="option.username as option in lookupOptions.users | orderBy: 'username' | propsFilter: {'username':  $select.search}">
                <div ng-bind-html="option.username | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                <small ng-bind-html="option.fullName | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
```

Comment: with ng-repeat="option as option in lookupOptions.users", is it working?

Comment: Unfortunately ng-model looks for the exact string value. So, select will be empty until and otherwise `log.username = 'DoeJ'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did:

Controller:

```
log.username = log.username ? log.username.toLowerCase() : "";
```

View:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label>Stored By</label>
        <ui-select ng-model="log.username" theme="bootstrap">
            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select Site">{{$select.selected.username}}</ui-select-match>
            <ui-select-choices repeat="option.username.toLowerCase() as option in lookupOptions.users | orderBy: 'username' | propsFilter: {'username':  $select.search}">
                <div ng-bind-html="option.username | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                <small ng-bind-html="option.fullName | highlight: $select.search"></small>
            </ui-select-choices>
        </ui-select>
    </div>
```